# xpath - Predicate with attribute issue

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a value which I am trying to trim down to 4 characters which is contained in an xml sub-element with the attribute WEIGHT.

```
  <addinfo>
    <info type="COMMODITY_CODE">39253000</info>
    <info type="WEIGHT">0.04700</info>
  </addinfo>
```

The full path is `documents/invoice/detailline/addinfo/info type="WEIGHT"`

My template says:

```
  <xsl:template match="documents/invoice/detailline/addinfo/info[@type='WEIGHT']">
<xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,  '0', '5')" />
</xsl:element>
```

It should be trimming the value 0.04700 down to a total of 4 characters (0.47). Instead it is doing this, but also eliminating the type attribute "WEIGHT".

Transform Output:

```
  <addinfo>
    <info type="COMMODITY_CODE">39253000</info>
    <info>0.04</info>
  </addinfo>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doing exactly what you're asking it to do: creating an element with the same name, and putting the trimmed value in it. To include the `type` attribute in the result, you can make a copy of it:

```
<xsl:template match="documents/invoice/detailline/addinfo/info[@type='WEIGHT']">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 4)" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

FYI, the numbering in `substring()` (and most other things in XPath) starts at 1, and the second and third parameters are numbers, not strings. I've fixed that above.

Comment: Thanks very much for that. At first it didn't work. But my mistake. I see what you did there. Many thanks!